# Jsoup given image scraping

Tags: java, jsoup

[image]

I want to get all those green underlined information using jsoup. And as selecter I want to use that red underlined div class hoverDiv
The code I am using is somewhat like below:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.mo").get();

links = doc.select("div.hoverDiv");
```

But it is not working...
So what should be the selecter?

Comment: Have you seen [this official tutorial](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)? If so could you show us what have you tried till now?

Comment: Yaah @Pshemo I tried something as below:

Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.mo").get();
links = doc.select("div.hoverDiv > rating");

Comment: Dont post your code in comment (it is hard to read). Instead add it to your question using [[edit]] option.

Comment: Sorry @Pshemo now I edited the question

Comment: I am trying with http://try.jsoup.org/
but still do not know how to do that... @Pshemo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

HTML you showed in your question is not code of the page but probably code generated by JavaScript after page is loaded. Try maybe this way

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.movieplus.com/hollywood/upcoming/").get();
Elements elements = doc.select(".ListDetails .ListData");
for (Element el : elements) {
    System.out.println(el.select("a[href]").first().attr("href"));
    System.out.println(el.select("img[title]").first().attr("title"));
    System.out.println(el.select(".mRate ,want").text());
    System.out.println(el.select(".relDate").text());
    System.out.println("----------");           
}
```

Comment: thanks but it is not working .... may be I could not mention the problem correctly. So i am giving the link : http://www.movieplus.com/hollywood/upcoming/

From this page I want to get all coming movies names, image url , release date, rating.
I will be really very grateful............ @Pshemo

Comment: what is that .ListDetails and .ListData  that is what should I use instead of them for the provided site.... I am not clear for the site ::: http://www.movieplus.com/hollywood/upcoming/   ..... @Pshemo

Comment: @exponentialFun take a look at result of `System.out.println(doc)` and you will see contend of page before JS, just like JSoup sees it.

Comment: you just absolute right. You    are a great helper sir... thanx